# Applet fails with AccessControlExceptions when running under JRE 7u21

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a self signed applet, which was running fine till jre 7u21 came around.

Now I get the following AccessControlException when calling java.net.ProxySelector.setDefault:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
("java.net.NetPermission" "setProxySelector")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ProxySelector.setDefault(Unknown Source)
```

For testing I tried removing this call, but other AccessControlExceptions start popping up. Apparently 7u21 applied significant changes to the applet's security model.

I always assumed that if the user accepts an applet's digital signature, no security restrictions apply. 7u21 now says that even signed applets can run in sandbox mode without clearly specifying when this is the case. ([7u21 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#blacklist)). My security level slider in the Java control panel is set to medium (lowest level). Any recommendations how to resolve this?

**Update:** I resolved it by adding the security tag

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

to the applet's jnlp file (applet is deployed via dtjava). It is now running under 7u21 without problems.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html